# Is it possible to copy a azure managed sql service database into an on-premise instance

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

I have a requirement to copy the azure managed sql service db into an on-premise instance.  But when I searched on the topic, I am able to find options for migrating on-premise to azure managed service instance.  But not the other way around.  Kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you don't want to synchronize those databases but just copy the database from Azure SQL to on-premises SQL.

In this case, you can simply [export the database as a BACPAC file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export) and [import it locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database?view=sql-server-ver15).